# WSO2am when integrated with ldap AD throws "Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712"

Tags: ldap, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have integrated WSO2am with AD and when i started WSO2am, it throws following error

> ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
>   -  Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker}
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException:
>   Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712.
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:134)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException:
>   Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftDataEndpoint.login(ThriftDataEndpoint.java:54)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:128)"

Comment: Is this a single node setup? and what is the APIM version?

Comment: yes, it is a single node setup.
i'm using apim2.5

Comment: i'm getting this error only after integrating ldap AD with wso2am2.5

Comment: Does the user defined in user-mst.xml exist in the AD? and has it the admin role?

Comment: yes it exist and it has admin role

Comment: are you sure this is the full error trace? seems like the bottom part is missing.